# error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Tags: library

I am working on a library to display custom text on a TFT screen and I came up with this error while making an example:

```
EsploraHelloWorld:31: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
   TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[5, 0], chars[5, 1], chars[5, 2], chars[5, 3], chars[5, 3], 120, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
               ^
```

Heres my code:

```
#include <Esplora.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT.h>
#include <TFTCharPlus.h>

// A table for all of the characters
const char chars[6][5] = {
  {0xf8, 0x20, 0xf8, 0x1f, 0x15},
  {0xf8, 0x08, 0x08, 0x1f, 0x01},
  {0x70, 0x88, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00},
  {0xc0, 0x20, 0xc6, 0x29, 0xc6},
  {0xf0, 0x40, 0x80, 0x5f, 0x01},
  {0xf0, 0x90, 0x60, 0x00, 0x3d}
};

TFTCharPlus TFTCharPlus();

void setup() {
  // initialize the screen
  EsploraTFT.begin();

  // make the background black
  EsploraTFT.background(0,0,0);

  // print the characters
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[0, 0], chars[0, 1], chars[0, 2], chars[0, 3], chars[0, 3], 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[1, 0], chars[1, 1], chars[1, 2], chars[1, 3], chars[1, 3], 24, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[2, 0], chars[2, 1], chars[2, 2], chars[2, 3], chars[2, 3], 48, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[3, 0], chars[3, 1], chars[3, 2], chars[3, 3], chars[3, 3], 72, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[4, 0], chars[4, 1], chars[4, 2], chars[4, 3], chars[4, 3], 96, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
  TFTCharPlus.drawChar(chars[5, 0], chars[5, 1], chars[5, 2], chars[5, 3], chars[5, 3], 120, 0, 255, 255, 255, 4, EsploraTFT);
}

void loop() {
  // not necessary
}
```

And for reference, here is the `drawChar()` function:

```
void TFTCharPlus::drawChar(byte data1, byte data2, byte data3, byte data4, byte data5, uint8_t xpos, uint8_t ypos, uint8_t colR, uint8_t colG, uint8_t colB, uint8_t size, TFT tft) {
  tft.stroke(colR, colG, colB);
  tft.fill(colR, colG, colB);
  byte data[5] = {data1, data2, data3, data4, data5};
  for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (uint8_t y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
      if (bitRead(data[x], 7 - y)) {
        tft.rect(x*size+xpos, y*size+ypos, size, size);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix the error?

**BTW**: The error is not in the library, everything is done correctly

**EDIT**: I realized that the error occurs on all six `drawChar()` lines, and After fixing a small error, I also got this:
`request for member 'drawChar' in 'TFTCharPlus', which is of non-class type 'TFTCharPlus()'`

Comment: what does line 30 and 31 say?

Comment: What I presume `TFTCharPlus` is a class, and class can not call the function. You have to define an object of the class and that will call the function.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are calling the "description" of the library method (function).  What is necessary is to use the "description" to create a "working copy" of the library method.  Then call the "working copy".

In the above statement, the "description" is the Class, "to create" means to instantiate and "working copy" is referred to as the Object.

In the [Arduino Serial Port Example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample), you will find the following line:

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
```

Here, the Class "SoftwareSerial" is used to instantiate the Object "mySerial".  Later in the code calls are made to the "write" method with in that object:

```
mySerial.write(Serial.read());
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
TFTCharPlus TFTCharPlus();
```

you've given your TFT object the same name as its class, making that name ambiguous. If you change the name of the object to, e.g.:

```
TFTCharPlus TFTobject();
```

as well as changing all of your references to it (`TFTobject.drawChar(...)`), it should fix the issue.